# Is There Anyway to conver dwg file in three.js acceptable format?

Tags: json, three.js, dwg

I an trying to use .dwg file in web app. I have recently find this (https://github.com/aalavandhaann/blueprint-js) works base on three.js file. while dwg is not compatible with three.js is there anyway to convert dwg file to json nad use it in threejs?

Comment: You could convert `DWG` to `STL` and then use [THREE.STLLoader](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl) to load the file. The conversion can be done with software like `AutoCAD`.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? A snippet of your code/attempt will help users of StackOverflow help you.